# Camera not working on MSI laptop

Tags: windows, camera, msi-laptop

Today started my MSI computer and the camera wasn't working.

Followed the steps in the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/camera-doesn-t-work-in-windows-32adb016-b29c-a928-0073-53d31da0dad5#WindowsVersion=Windows_10) but none worked. Yet, discovered that the Device Manager didn't have the Camera.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it had to go to the MSI Center > Features > General Settings and turn on the Camera.

[image: MSI Center turn on Camera]

Now the camera shows up in the Device Manager

[image]